# Security risks/benefits of using Google voice?

Tags: encryption, mobile, voip, google-apps

A small business that handles sensitive information needs to implement a VOIP system that provides better security than the regular cellular network.

What are the security risks/benefits of using Google Voice for Mobile? Are there any other apps/systems that should be considered?

Threat model: More sophisticated eavesdroppers, such as professional hackers. Not worried about eavesdropping by NSA or other authorities.

Comment: You can implement your own VoIP with VPNs. Then you can use it from mobiles, and I know few people who managed to do it on the same premise, however I don't know the very details except it's standard enterprise VoIP and enterprise VPNs.